# Sum can not exceed 100 in HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a table where you can write some number (the number represents how many balls you want to allocate among three choices). I would like the total number not to exceed 100. And possibly if the sum is over to display an error message.

```
<table class="table-bordered" style=" width: 80%; margin-left: 10%;" >
      <tr style="background-color:#ffb380">
            <td scope="col"  colspan="1" style="text-align:center"> Quanti Gettoni per Scelta 1 </td>
            <td scope="col"  colspan="1" style="text-align:center"> Quanti Gettoni per Scelta 2 </td>
            <td scope="col"  colspan="1" style="text-align:center"> Quanti Gettoni per Scelta 3 </td>
            <td scope="col"  colspan="1" style="text-align:center"> Totale Gettoni Assegnati </td>

      </tr>
      <tr style="background-color:#ffe0cc">
            <td> <input class="pref_input" id="pref1" type="number" name="pref1" min="0" max="100"> </td>
            <td> <input class="pref_input" id="pref2" type="number" name="pref2" min="0" max="100"> </td>
            <td> <input class="pref_input" id="pref3" type="number" name="pref3" min="0" max="100"> </td>
            <td> <span id="avginc" ></span> </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<script>window.onload = init_average();

function init_average(){
    avginc =  document.getElementById("avginc");
    pref1 = document.getElementById("pref1");
    pref2 = document.getElementById("pref2");
    pref3 = document.getElementById("pref3");

  document.querySelectorAll('.pref_input').forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('change', event => {
        sum_prefs = get_input_value(pref1) + get_input_value(pref2) + get_input_value(pref3);
        avginc.innerHTML = parseFloat(sum_prefs );
    })
  })

}
function get_input_value(input){
    if(input.value == ''){
    return 0;
  }
  else {
    return parseFloat(input.value);
  }
  if(input.value >= 100) {
  return 'La somma di gettoni non può essere maggiore di 100';}
  }

</script>
```

Comment: What are you using to perform the sum?

Comment: Also I forgot, the sum must be 100

Comment: That's what I would like to know :)

Comment: aah! use JavaScript. - Start here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript

Comment: I tried something like

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how much you were able to proceed with this, but here is one way of getting this done.

The trick is to check whether the sum is greater than 100, if yes keep the sum to 100 and toggle a css class on an error div. All three sections are given below.

**HTML**

```
<table class="table-bordered" style=" width: 80%; margin-left: 10%;">
  <tr style="background-color:#ffb380">
    <td scope="col" colspan="1" style="text-align:center"> Quanti Gettoni per Scelta 1 </td>
    <td scope="col" colspan="1" style="text-align:center"> Quanti Gettoni per Scelta 2 </td>
    <td scope="col" colspan="1" style="text-align:center"> Quanti Gettoni per Scelta 3 </td>
    <td scope="col" colspan="1" style="text-align:center"> Totale Gettoni Assegnati </td>

  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:#ffe0cc">
    <td> <input class="pref_input" id="pref1" type="number" name="pref1" min="0" max="100"> </td>
    <td> <input class="pref_input" id="pref2" type="number" name="pref2" min="0" max="100"> </td>
    <td> <input class="pref_input" id="pref3" type="number" name="pref3" min="0" max="100"> </td>
    <td> <span id="avginc"></span> </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="error" class="hide">Error message</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.show{
  display: block;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```js
window.onload = init_average();

function init_average() {
  avginc = document.getElementById("avginc");
  pref1 = document.getElementById("pref1");
  pref2 = document.getElementById("pref2");
  pref3 = document.getElementById("pref3");

  document.querySelectorAll(".pref_input").forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
      sum_prefs =
        get_input_value(pref1) +
        get_input_value(pref2) +
        get_input_value(pref3);
      let sum = parseFloat(sum_prefs);
      if (sum > 100) {
        sum = 100;
        document.getElementById("error").className = "show";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("error").className = "hide";
      }
      avginc.innerHTML = sum;
    });
  });
}
function get_input_value(input) {
  if (input.value == "") {
    return 0;
  } else {
    return parseFloat(input.value);
  }
  if (input.value >= 100) {
    return "La somma di gettoni non può essere maggiore di 100";
  }
}
```

Here is the codepen https://codepen.io/aksappy/pen/VwPKKbj

Answer (score -1):

Yeah it worked. Just a minor correction, change Error message to "La somma di gettoni non può essere maggiore di 100", otherwise ERROR MESSAGE is displayed
Thanks